# Is there a way to integrate Git into the Windows cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, cmd

Is there a way to integrate Git into the Windows cmd or PowerShell? - so that it feels a bit like a Linux terminal. How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download and install Git as shown in [**the link**](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). In the **sixth** slide, 'Adjusting your PATH environment.', check for the option **'Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows command prompt'** and that's it!

Answer (score 13):

OK, I got it myself ...

```
new-item -path alias:git -value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe'
```

Comment: or `new-item -path alias:git -value 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe'` these days

Answer (score 10):

This is what I use: [posh-git: a PowerShell environment for Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

It also integrates into the cwd line:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out Posh Git:

- *[Better Git with PowerShell](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx)*
- *[Configure Git in PowerShell So You Don’t Have to Enter Your Password All the Damn Time](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/)*

Answer (score 2):

Simple and straightforward way:

*[Step by Step guide](http://thepracticalsysadmin.com/setting-up-git-in-windows/)*

Essentially

1. Add Git binaries to the system path

Answer (score 0):

why everybody here wants to literally "integrate" git into powershell?

1. in powershell type `git`
2. now you are in bash  (otherwise you don't have git as an env var)

but if you really want an integration, the easiest way is to "Download and install posh-git"