# Install python using chocolatey on shared windows gitlab runner (powershell)

Tags: python, windows, continuous-integration, gitlab, chocolatey

I'm trying to set up an automatic python build on windows using [shared windows runners on gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/windows.html#windows-development).  I am able to install python using chocolatey, but when I try to use python, I get the error:

```
python -m pip install numpy
The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have tried using the `refreshenv` command as recommended [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/python), but it gives me the result

`Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe.` This sugests that the powershell profile is not loaded. Ordinarily I would restart the powershell window to reload the profile but I cannot do that in the CI pipeline.

How can I use python in the current powershell window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh the environment of a PowerShell session after a Chocolatey install without needing to open a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758437/how-to-refresh-the-environment-of-a-powershell-session-after-a-chocolatey-instal)