# Reload Powershell Console

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying a script that installs several applications.

```
choco install nvm; 
nvm install 12;
```

These commands works fine when they ran in separate sessions. After executing
choco install nvm;
I have to restart the powershell console and execute the second command. How to overcome this?
As far I searched I came to know that I have to use 'dotsource'.
But I dont know to do this. Any help?

Comment: [`Update-SessionEnvironment`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/functions/update-sessionenvironment) updates the current session with environment-variable changes after a `choco install` command

Comment: hi @mklement0 , it didnt worked for me , Update-SessionEnvironment throws the same error. Update-SessionEnvironment is not recognized as name.... Also I tried refreshenv, its working but it is not helping to solve my problem. I still have to restart powershell to complete the installation.

Comment: Sorry man... After importing this module it worked....Import-Module "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"

Comment: Glad to hear it, @jimmy20, though it's curious that this module wasn't loaded automatically, via your `$PROFILE`. Normally this should only be a problem immediately after installing Chocolatey itself, in the same session - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760714/45375).

Comment: Yes...Am installing it in the same session...Anyway thanks man